# How do I determine the correct commend for running a PHP CLI script?

Tags: php, command, cgi, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script which uses the following code to execute another PHP script in the background:

```
exec("php myScript.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

On my development server myScript.php is run using PHP CLI (I have checked using php_sapi_name()), and operates as expected. However, on the live server the script appears to run using PHP CGI. This results in the server trying to run an infinite number of the same script and my scripting privileges being suspended.

I have seen various suggestions for what the correct command for running a PHP CLI script can be (depending on the exact server configuration), including "php" (which is what my development server uses), "php-cli", "php5" and "php5-cli". Is there any way that I can determine which is the correct command on the live web server? Obviously, I am not keen to dive in and try them out one-by-one as an incorrect choice may get me suspended again.

Comment: i don't see why the user\owner of php should effect how your scripts run; especially "This results in the server trying to run an infinite number of the same script "

Comment: I suspect the large number of CGI instances is caused by your CGI script waiting for a return value from the CLI call. Try using `cron` for background tasks instead.

Comment: Is this your server or a hosted solution.  You might not have exec privileges or missing a PHP extension.  Can u remote in to server and test manually running the script in CLI?

Comment: Are you calling this `exec` function inside a loop? Does that loop terminate? Does myscript.php contain another exec call in a loop? Theres a number of factors which may cause an infinate spawn. Most of which boil down to a non-terminating loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hosting provider was eventually able to provide me with the name of the PHP CLI install on their machines. It had an obscure name (php43). Should anyone else run in to issues where they need to execute a script using PHP CLI instead of PHP CGP then you may well need to ask your hosting provider for the details. Unfortunately I found that it took a while to get hold of someone who understood my question and could ask the correct person what the answer was, so you may need to be very clear and patient with them!

Answer (score 0):

Your "exec()" will return almost instantly, so if it's in a loop you could spawn zillions of them, as already noted.

You'll need to detail whether your seeing a bunch of instances of script abruptly running at once, or whether they just seem to build up over time as though they're not exiting.

There are a number if issues known about PHP an exec, some involving several being run at once by end users and various bad effects and workarounds:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
  http://forums.iis.net/t/1149467.aspx?Too+many+php+cgi+s

The php-cgi sprawl problem is allegedly not shared by mod_php and FastCGI, so if you can switch to those instead your problem might just vanish.  This makes some assumptions about what userid you need stamped on the PHP program when it's running, but if that's an issue, using the stuff below together with suexec can provide flexibility on the user ID used.

Here's an option to keep the calling script from having to know details about the implementation of the subscript, which incidentally lets you call it simply by name both via the exec and from the PHP CLI mode like you're probably already doing to test it.

```
$ cat the-php-script   # /usr/bin/php5 below would also work.
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
print("hi\n");
?>
$ chmod 755 the-php-script 
$ ls -l the-php-script 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username 39 Sep  2 22:37 the-php-script
$ ./the-php-script 
hi
$
```

In theory that should allow: exec("/...pathname_to.../myScript >/dev/null 2>&1 &").
The only difference in functionality is that it nails down which PHP interprets the script.